# Python - Parallel Deocder Convert 2's Complment to Hexadecimal

Tags: python

i have the code for a parallel decoder which converts parallel binary bit to hexadecimal. How can I modify it to convert 2's complement to Hexadecimal? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
def decode(self):
    # Determine which (optional) channels have input data. Insist in
    # a non-empty input data set. Cope with sparse connection maps.
    # Store enough state to later "compress" sampled input data.
    max_possible = len(self.optional_channels)
    idx_channels = [
        idx if self.has_channel(idx) else None
        for idx in range(max_possible)
    ]
    has_channels = [idx for idx in idx_channels if idx is not None]
    if not has_channels:
        raise ChannelError('At least one channel has to be supplied.')
    max_connected = max(has_channels)

    # Determine .wait() conditions, depending on the presence of a
    # clock signal. Either inspect samples on the configured edge of
    # the clock, or inspect samples upon ANY edge of ANY of the pins
    # which provide input data.
    if self.has_channel(0):
        edge = self.options['clock_edge'][0]
        conds = {0: edge}
    else:
        conds = [{idx: 'e'} for idx in has_channels]

    # Pre-determine which input data to strip off, the width of
    # individual items and multiplexed words, as well as format
    # strings here. This simplifies call sites which run in tight
    # loops later.
    idx_strip = max_connected + 1
    num_item_bits = idx_strip - 1
    num_word_items = self.options['wordsize']
    num_word_bits = num_item_bits * num_word_items
    num_digits = (num_item_bits + 3) // 4
    self.fmt_item = "{{:0{}x}}".format(num_digits)
    num_digits = (num_word_bits + 3) // 4
    self.fmt_word = "{{:0{}x}}".format(num_digits)

    # Keep processing the input stream. Assume "always zero" for
    # not-connected input lines. Pass data bits (all inputs except
    # clock) to the handle_bits() method.
    while True:
        (clk, d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7) = self.wait(conds)
        pins = (clk, d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7)
        bits = [0 if idx is None else pins[idx] for idx in idx_channels]
        item = bitpack(bits[1:idx_strip])
        self.handle_bits(item, num_item_bits)
```

2's complement example:

```
0011001

apply two's complement
1. inverse the bits, 1100110
2. add a binary digit, 1100110 + 1 = 1100111
```

Comment: Perhaps this code I wrote is of use?  https://gist.github.com/the-moog/db87287845ef877afb691b8452def43d

Comment: Could you provide a [Reproducible Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Or at least an example of the effect of the `decode` function ?

Comment: @JasonM Thanks for the help! Will surely look into that.